# ColdFusion updates - cumulative?

Tags: coldfusion, patch, coldfusion-10

I can not seem to find a definitive answer to this on Adobe sites.  Working with ColdFusion 10,11 or even 2016, are the updates (hotfixes) cumulative?

For example, ColdFusion has hotfixes up to hotfix_023.jar.  Does this jar include all previous hotfixes as well?  Or if I want to have a fully patched CF 10 server do I need to install ALL of them?

I would have emailed tech support @ Adobe, but CF10 is EOL so they won't answer any questions.

Thank you!

Comment: Check [the release notes](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-10-update-23.html).  "This update is cumulative and includes fixes from previous ColdFusion 10 updates."

Comment: @Ageax - yep that's what I missed.  Thank you so much for finding that!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ColdFusion updates are cumulative. 
For CF10, please make sure you apply the mandatory update before applying the latest patch. 
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-10-mandatory-update.html